# How to attach aptana debugger to a Padrino or Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, debugging, sinatra, aptana, padrino

I'm using Aptana for a Padrino app, but I don't know how to attach the debugger once the server is running.

I've installed the ruby-debug-ide gem and the Aptana Firefox extenstion.

What's the correct debug configuration for setting that up?

Also, when I try to toggle a breakpoint in Aptana I don't get the standard eclipse marker to show that it's doing something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to debug the ruby code or javascript? Also relevant is the version of Studio you're running.

If you are trying to debug the ruby code...

For Aptana Studio 3, you can launch any ruby script under the debugger by right-clicking the file and choosing Debug As > Ruby application. You can also edit the launch configuration it generates (or create one manually) to tweak it to work.

Suppose your sinatra app is started from "myapp.rb". You right-click it, and choose Debug As > Ruby Application. It will likely fail the first time, but will generate a launch config to work with. Go to Run > Debug Configurations, select the entry for myapp.rb and then edit the arguments (i.e. add "-rubygems" to the Interpreter args). The output might not auto-flush out to the console, because of the bug/ticket here: https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/2355-force-stdoutstderr-sync-to-true-to-flush-output-on-ruby-launches

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but I adapted a hint for RubyMine found here:
http://blog.stevehorn.cc/blog?tag=rubymine

Aptana 3 on my MAC stops, but unfortunately - if you debug Padrino - it always shows up 'routing.rb' as if the break was there. Interestingly on the same line as in the file you intend to debug. I have filed a bug.

HTH